# I can't invoke the method defined in the subclass

Tags: java

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Animal {
    
    protected String name;
    int age;
    
    
    public Animal(String name, int age) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public static void eating() {
        System.out.println("eating");
    }
}
```

```
public class Human extends Animal{

    public Human(String name, int age) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(name, age);
    }
    
    
    public static void talking() {
        System.out.println("Talk");
    }
}
```

main program:

```
public class program {
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
    
        Animal hum = new Human("bob", 1);
        
        System.out.println(hum);
        //hum.talking();
        
    }

}
```

The output of the main program is *wk05.Human@7f690630*. So why I can't do "hum.talking" in the main program? My understanding of inheritance is that the subclass can invoke the methods defined in the parent class as well as the method defined in the subclass.

Comment: If you want to demonstrate polymorphism and/or inheritance, you don't want to use `static` on a method.

Comment: Besides that, Java is a strongly typed language.  You must declare (or cast) `hum` as type `Human` or it won't let you make the call.

Comment: @markspace But why I can run this code if I do "hum.eating()". There is no error occur

Comment: Because `eating()` is a method on the type `Animal`, which is what you have declared.

Comment: The visibility of members is based on the _declared type_, not the _actual runtime type_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your program `Animal hum = new Human("bob", 1);` means hum reference to `Animal` super class which does not have definition of `talking()` and object is `Human`.

At compile time reference is considered rather than the object. Object is used at runtime. So if you want to call `talking()` you would need to:

**1) Create reference to Human class**
Here the reference is also to `Human` class so it has the definition of `talking()` method at compile time.

```
Human hum = new Human("bob", 1);
hum.talking();
```

**2) Cast object to Human (only for understanding the type-casting)**
When we cast the object we explicitly tell the compiler to refer the defined object. So it can refer that.

```
Animal hum = new Human("bob", 1);
((Human) hum).talking();
```

Reason behind is that let's say you have one more class `SuperHuman` which also extends `Animal` class and that class doesn't have `talking()` method then how the compiler would be knowing that reference `hum` will be referring `Human` or `SuperHuman`?

And let's say during initialization you have we have done like `Animal hum = new Human("bob", 1);` and later in code the `hum` is updated to `hum = SuperHuman("sup", 10);`. That's the reason compile time reference is referred and Object is referred at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The error is a *compile* error; the compiler doesn’t care what the object type *actually* is (or could be), it only cares about what it’s *declared* as.

Also, I’m almost certain your methods should not be static.

If you were to do something like what you’re exploring, you have to abstract out the method, either as an interface or an abstract method. For example:

```
class abstract Animal {
    abstract void communicate();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    void communicate() {
        System.out.println("bark");
    }
}

class Human extends Animal {
    void communicate() {
        System.out.println("talk");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Gaurav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4762502/gaurav-jeswani) says you have to create a reference to `Human` or cast `Animal` to `Human`. But inheritance would make more sense if Animal were an interface or an abstract class (What I don't particularly like to do) and exposed a method in which all derived classes should have to implement.

```
public interface Animal {

    String getName();
    int getAge();
    void blab();
}

public class Human implements Animal {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    Human(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    
    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public void blab() {
        System.out.println("Talk");
    }
}
```

And the main

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Human("Bob", 1);
        animal.blab();
    }
}
```